# Determine whether series converges or diverges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{5\pi}{3}n\right)}{n^{\frac{5\pi}{3}}}$$

Hello, 
I thought about using Squeeze Theorem but the 5π/3 threw me off.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the series absolutely convergent?

Comment: Notice that $n^{\frac{5\pi}{3}} \geq n^{5}$ for $n \geq 1$

Comment: Since you received the answers, using  MathNewbie's comment, let me give you a nice result $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{5\pi}{3}n\right)}{n^5}=-\frac{17 \pi ^5}{5832}\approx -0.892033$$ while for your summation the result is $\approx -0.888248$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the absolute value of the sine function is bounded by 1 and that the exponent on n is greater than 1.

Thus by the p-test this series converges absolutely.

Comment: Ah, so it is bounded. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the series is convergent, use Dirichlet's test for Convergence. Observe that $\sum_{k=1}^n \sin(k\theta$) is always bounded and the sequence $\frac1{n^\alpha}$ is decreasing and converges to zero. For every $\alpha>0$. But in this case the siplest way is to compare the series with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^2}$ to prove that it's absolutely convergent.

Comment: Thank you. I also really appreciate Dirichlet's test as explanation.

Comment: How $\sum_{k=1}^n \sin(k\theta$) is always bounded ???

Comment: Is $cosec(n\theta)$ always bounded ?

Comment: Use this identity $$\sum_{k=1}^n \sin(k\theta) =\frac{\sin(\frac{n\theta}2)\sin(\frac{(n+1)\theta}2)}{\sin(\frac{\theta}2)}$$

Comment: I know it...whose absolute value $\le |cosec(\theta/2)|$. For $\theta=2\pi$ what happens ??  Not always bounded...For this particular case it is bounded

Comment: I mean that your statement ' Observe that $\sum_{k=1}^n \sin(k\theta$) is **always**  bounded ' is FALSE..

Comment: When $\sin(\frac\theta2)=0$, then $\sin(k\theta)=0$, so if the denominator in the above identity get's zero, then the series is sum of zeroes...